# Accessibility in HighCharts stock

Tags: highcharts, accessibility, stock

We are trying to get a *highchart-stocks chart fully accesible* for both, **keyboard **and **voiceover**

We have detected that the HighStock stock-tools module does not correctly add the necessary elements in the DOM it generates so that accessibility is persistent in the HTML structure, for example, in the list it generates, it does not incorporate the tabindex attribute in the same way as Yes it is added when using the exporting export module:

**HTML for exporting:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvNyi.png)

**stocktools HTML:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkLUE.png)

As you can see, the tabindex attribute is not included in the second case.

On the other hand, semantically it is not being constructed correctly for the  elements within each “li”. This does not allow correct use of the “voiceover” option.

It would be interesting if the structure were more semantic with “buttons”, “tabindex” and “aria-label” or “role” where necessary within each module, or at least within the stocktools module.

Keyboard access to the popup is also not allowed, which affects the user's usability experience.

**Could you please let us know if we are missing something or there are any other modules to use for accesibility related to highchart stocks charts?**

thank you in advanced

Comment: Hi, thank you for reporting this issue! Could you please create a ticket on our GitHub page: [Highcharts GitHub Issues](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose)? Our accessibility team will investigate and propose possible solutions. Thanks!

Comment: done: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/20267
thanks